# Tint UIImageView permanently

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tintcolor

I'd like to tint a UIImageView, but as of now when I tint it and use the control (for example a button press), the tint disappears. Any thoughts?

```
class func tintImageView(imageView : UIImageView, withColor color:UIColor) {

    var coloredImage = imageView.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = coloredImage
    imageView.tintColor = color
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The button's `controlState` probably changed, and each `controlState` has its own imageView.